# Does Scala have a global object or class?

Tags: scala

I know programmers are supposed to wrap their code in an application object:

```
object Hello extends App {
  println("Hello, World")
}
```

It is required in Eclipse, if I ever want to get any output. However, when I tried to write some code (very casually) in Emacs, I write like this:

```
class Pair[+T](val first: T, val second: T)

trait Friend[-T] {
  def befriend(someone: T)
}

def makeFriendWith(s: Student, f: Friend[Student]) {
  f.befriend(s)
}
```

It seems like there is no universal object or class that wraps over the function `makeFriendWith`. Is Scala like JavaScript, everything is attached to a global object? If not, what is this function attached to?

Also why can this work in console (I complied it with `scala` command and it worked) but does not work in Eclipse? What's the use of the Application object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a JVM language, Scala cannot truly create any top-level entities other than classes and interfaces.

It does, however, have the notion of a "package object" which creates the illusion of value entites (`val`, `var` and `def`) not enclosed in a class or trait.

See http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/packageobjects/packageobjects.html for information on package objects.

Comment: Did this answer the questions?  I thought not, but maybe it's just me.

Comment: I added a link to the package object documentation. I consider them a pretty minor feature of the language and rarely use them.

Answer (score 5):

Scala doesn't have top-level defs, but your script can be run by either the REPL or the scala script runner.

The precise behavior of your script depends on which way you run it.

The REPL can run scripts line-by-line or whole hog.  (Compare `:paste` and `:paste -raw` versus `:load` or `-i init.script` and the future option `-I init.script`.)

There is an [issue about sensitive scripting](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4625).  The script runner should realize if you're trying to run an `App`.

There is [another effort](https://github.com/som-snytt/scala/commit/e1663810ff11ccb2b7605c7e7ce9ea29506ed6d1) to make scripting a compiler phase that is easily customized. Scroll to `Scripter.scala` for code comments about its current heuristics.

In short, your defs must be wrapped in a top-level entity, but exactly how that happens is context-dependent.

There was [a recent effort](https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/3123) to make an alternative baked-in wrapping scheme available for the REPL.

None of this is mandated by the language spec, any more than special rules pertaining to `sbt` build files are defined by the language.

Answer (score 2):

You can define methods like this *only* in the console, which (behind the scenes) automatically wraps them in an anonymous class for you.

Outside of the console, there's no such luxury.

Answer (score 0):

You *can* run code like this directly in Eclipse: use [Scala worksheet](https://github.com/scala-ide/scala-worksheet/wiki/Getting-Started). IntelliJ IDEA Scala plugin supports it as well.